# Not able to extract different array name from json file

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have multiple JSON files like below.

```
{
  "09800214851900C3": {
    "label": "P7-R1-R16:S2",
    "name": "Geist Upgradable rPDU",
    "state": "normal",
    "order": 0,
    "type": "i03",
    "snmpInstance": 1,
    "lifetimeEnergy": "20155338",
    "outlet": {},
    "alarm": {
      "severity": "",
      "state": "none"
    },
    "layout": {
      "0": [
        "entity/total0",
        "entity/phase0",
        "entity/phase1",
        "entity/phase2"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

from this, I want to extract like below using jq

```
09800214851900C3 : P7-R1-R16:S2
```

I facing an issue that this array value {09800214851900C3} is not the same as all the JSON files. So I need help to extract the same.

Answer (score 2):

Based on data format, Assuming you need first key in object and its value of label.

Use `Object.keys` to get object keys and get the need value without hardcoding.

```js
const data = {
  "09800214851900C3": {
    "label": "P7-R1-R16:S2",
    "name": "Geist Upgradable rPDU",
    "state": "normal",
    "order": 0,
    "type": "i03",
    "snmpInstance": 1,
    "lifetimeEnergy": "20155338",
    "outlet": {},
    "alarm": {
      "severity": "",
      "state": "none"
    },
    "layout": {
      "0": [
        "entity/total0",
        "entity/phase0",
        "entity/phase1",
        "entity/phase2"
      ]
    }
  }
};


const extract = (key = Object.keys(data)[0], `${key} : ${data[key].label}`);

console.log(extract)
```

Comment: Thanks Siva. But i want the help using jq query

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I extract 1st key by using below jq query

```
jsonfile.json | jq -r '.keys[]'
```

based on that i parse the key into another jq query to get the label value as well.

```
jsonfile.json | jq -r '.09800214851900C3.label'
```